# Is there a PHP function that joins arrays of separate fields into an array of grouped fields?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a PHP function that takes multiple arrays (each array representing a collection of a single field's values, such as first-names) and outputs an array whose values group these fields together?

For example:

```
$arr1 = ['John', 'Kyle']; // first names
$arr2 = ['Smith', 'Andrews']; // last names
$arr3 = ['john@example.com', 'kyle@example.com']; // email addresses
// ...

Output:

Array(
  0 => ['John', 'Smith', 'john@example.com'],
  1 => ['Kyle', 'Andrews', 'kyle@example.com'],
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with null as the first parameter to merge them...

> **NULL** can be passed as a value to callback to perform a zip operation
>   on multiple arrays. If only array1 is provided, array_map() will
>   return the input array.

So

```
print_r(array_map(null, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3));
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Smith
            [2] => john@example.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kyle
            [1] => Andrews
            [2] => kyle@example.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a build in function in PHP for that, but you can merge it manually like this:

```
$arr1 = ['John', 'Kyle']; // first names
$arr2 = ['Smith', 'Andrews']; // last names
$arr3 = ['john@example.com', 'kyle@example.com']; // email addresses

$merged = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $name) {
    if (isset($arr2[$key]) && isset($arr3[$key])) {
        $merged[] = [$name, $arr2[$key], $arr3[$key]];
    }
}
 var_dump($merged);

 // output: array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "John" [1]=> string(5) "Smith" [2]=> string(16) "john@example.com" } 
    [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "Kyle" [1]=> string(7) "Andrews" [2]=> string(16) "kyle@example.com" } }
```